# Перевод консольного приложения python для windows на консольное приложение пайтон для Андроид

Tags: android, python, windows, python-3.6

Есть ли способ компиляции такой штуки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python не компилируется. Для запуска на смартфоне используйте приложение, например pyDroid. Либо Kivy. Тогда появляется возможность даже использовать графические и мультимедиа воможности.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, по теории, можно скомпилить в си++ где-нибудь здесь: https://www.javainuse.com/py2cpp
И потом в эксэшник, для си++ проблем с компиляцией нет. Но там может так себе скомпилить ЛИБО: если в коде есть импорты:
вариант 1. Советую проверить код си перед компиляцией
вариант 2. Можно поставить pyinstaller и командой "pyinstaller --onefile <file.py>" скомпилить, но весить будет минимум 4 мб.